# shell sendto on windows 10 does not work anymore

Tags: windows-10

On previous Windows you could open the sendto folder by typing `shell:sendto` in menu. It doesn't work anymore I tried in Cortana input because I can't see where to get the old command input.

Comment: it work using a run command, what do you mean by menu?

Comment: @Moab OK thanks I didn't see the run command on Windows 10 but I got it by typing run with Cortana

Comment: Win+R gets you a run box. "cmd" as a run command gets you a command prompt.

Comment: Oops, I had the page open from ages ago and answered without refreshing. Sorry if my response was unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

### Use <kbd>Win+R</kbd> (Run)

- Paste `shell:sendto` it into a run prompt

[image]

### Use Explorer

- Paste `shell:sendto` it into any address bar in explorer

[image]

Comment: I was trying to create a shell script (bat file) that would open it because I couldn't remember this syntax.  Typing `shell:sendto` into a `CMD.EXE` window, however, doesn't work.  Your answer helped me fix this.  The command to use is `explorer shell:sendto` and viola, it works.  Now I can create a batch file `OpenSendToFolder.bat` to open this folder.